how to calculate cross correlation between rows or columns of two 2D numpy arrays
the SciPy's scipy.signal.correlate function supports computing the cross-correlation between two 1D arrays. However, there is no direct support for axis-wise cross-correlation between two 2D arrays of the same shape. For example, computing the cross-correlation between each row (or column) pair across two 2D arrays currently requires implementing a Python for loop. This limitation becomes frustrating when dealing with large datasets, as loops are computationally inefficient, and workarounds can be non-intuitive for many users.
It would be great if there is an option to add a parameter to the scipy.signal.correlate function (e.g., axis) that allows computation of axis-wise cross-correlation between two 2D arrays as shown in the example below
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import correlate

# Two 2D arrays of the same shape
A = np.random.rand(1000, 100)
B = np.random.rand(1000, 100)

# Compute axis-wise cross-correlation along rows
result = correlate(A, B, axis=1, mode='full')


Consider two arrays $A$ and $B$ of shape $(N, M)$. Let $A_{i,m}$ denote the element of $A$ in row $i$ and column $m$, with indices $0 \le i < N$ and $0 \le m < M$. Define polynomials for each row $i$ by
$$
p_i(z) = \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} A_{i,m}z^m,
\quad
q_i(z) = \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} B_{i,m}z^m.
$$
To compute the cross-correlation of row $i$ in $A$ with the corresponding row $i$ in $B$, one typically evaluates
$$
c_i(k) = \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} A_{i,m}B_{i,m + k},
$$
where $m + k$ is treated as invalid if it lies outside $[0, M-1]$. This sum can be interpreted as the coefficient of $z^k$ in the product
$$
p_i(z)\widetilde{q_i}(z),
$$
where
$$
\widetilde{q_i}(z) = \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} B_{i,M-1-m}z^m.
$$
Reversing the coefficients in $q_i$ accounts for the time reversal required by cross-correlation. If
$$
p_i(z) = \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} a_{m}z^m,
\quad
\widetilde{q_i}(z) = \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} b_{m}z^m,
$$
then the product
$$
p_i(z)\widetilde{q_i}(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{2M-2} \Bigl(\sum_{m=0}^{k} a_m b_{k-m}\Bigr) z^k
$$
recovers exactly the discrete cross-correlation values as coefficients of $z^k$ for $k$ ranging from $-(M-1)$ to $M-1$, once we align indices appropriately and treat out-of-range values as zero. A creative global construction is to assemble each row’s polynomial $p_i(z)$ and its reversed partner $\widetilde{q_i}(z)$ into a block-diagonal matrix form, so that the entire row-wise cross-correlation becomes extracting the block-diagonal polynomial products’ coefficients.
Below is a Python implementation that illustrates this polynomial perspective directly. Each row $i$ is treated as a polynomial $p_i(z)$ multiplied by a reversed polynomial $\widetilde{q_i}(z)$, and we collect the resulting coefficients. Although the code implements the idea row-by-row, it mirrors the mathematical construction of polynomial multiplication:
import numpy as np

def polynomial_cross_correlation(A, B):
    """
    A and B are both of shape (N, M).
    Returns an array of shape (N, 2*M - 1) where each row i is the
    cross-correlation of A[i] and B[i].
    """
    A = np.asarray(A)
    B = np.asarray(B)
    N, M = A.shape
    if B.shape != (N, M):
        raise ValueError("A and B must have the same shape.")
    
    # Result will have shape (N, 2*M - 1) for 'full' cross-correlation
    result = np.zeros((N, 2*M - 1), dtype=A.dtype)
    
    # For each row i, we treat A[i] and B[i] as polynomial coefficients
    # p_i(z) = sum_{m=0}^{M-1} A_{i,m} z^m
    # q_i(z) -> reversed => tilde{q_i}(z) = sum_{m=0}^{M-1} B_{i, M-1-m} z^m
    # We then compute the product p_i(z)*tilde{q_i}(z)
    # The coefficient of z^k in that product is the cross-correlation for lag k - (M - 1).
    
    for i in range(N):
        # Row polynomials
        p_i = A[i]
        q_i_reversed = B[i][::-1]
        
        # Naive polynomial multiplication
        # p_i has length M, q_i_reversed has length M, product has length 2*M - 1
        row_result = np.zeros(2*M - 1, dtype=A.dtype)
        for m in range(M):
            for n in range(M):
                row_result[m + n] += p_i[m] * q_i_reversed[n]
        
        # row_result now holds the cross-correlation coefficients for row i in 'full' mode
        result[i] = row_result
    
    return result

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    np.random.seed(0)
    A = np.random.rand(5, 4)
    B = np.random.rand(5, 4)
    cc = polynomial_cross_correlation(A, B)
    print("Shape of cross-correlation result:", cc.shape)
    print("Result:\n", cc)

Each row of the result corresponds to the discrete cross-correlation of the matching row in $A$ and $B$. The reversing of coefficients in $q_i$ captures the essential time flip inherent in correlation. The polynomial multiplication loop then calculates each coefficient in the product, which maps exactly to each possible lag. This solution embodies a mathematical construction that regards each row of the input arrays as a polynomial and extracts cross-correlation via polynomial coefficient extraction, avoiding explicit reference to shifting indices in a time series.

thank you for your detailed response.But your Python function needs N*M^2 for loop iterations which is much slower than going through M or N iterations using the native Scipy.linalg.correlate function
